# Repeat Rows Between Date Values in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table:

```
id | start_date | end_date
----------------------------
01 | 2016-02-19 | 2017-03-02
02 | 2017-06-19 | 2018-09-11
03 | 2015-03-19 | 2018-05-02
04 | 2018-02-19 | 2018-01-05
05 | 2014-06-19 | 2018-07-25
```

and I would like to repeat rows based on the time between `start_date` and `end_date`, in this case by years extracted from those two date columns. My desired result would resemble:

```
id | year
=========
01 | 2016
01 | 2017
02 | 2017
02 | 2018
03 | 2015
03 | 2016
03 | 2017
03 | 2018
04 | 2018
05 | 2014
05 | 2015
05 | 2016
05 | 2017
05 | 2018
```

How can I achieve this in Redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try joining with a calendar table containing all years which would appear in your table:

```
WITH years AS (
    SELECT 2014 AS year UNION ALL
    SELECT 2015 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2018
)

SELECT
    t2.id,
    t1.year
FROM years t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.year BETWEEN DATE_PART('year', t2.start_date) AND DATE_PART('year', t2.end_date)
ORDER BY
    t2.id,
    t1.year;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note: Use `DATE_PART(year, t2.start_date)` for Redshift, where the datetime component does not take single quotes.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Tested and working. How could I do this without explicitly specifying the years in the calendar table? My first thought was `WITH years AS ( SELECT generate_series(2014, 2018, 1) AS year )` but I am getting an error in Redshift: `INFO:  Function "generate_series(integer,integer,integer)" not supported.
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`

Comment: Well telling by the error message, `generate_series` is not available on Redshift, which is based on an old fork from Postgres.  Search around for generating series in Redshift if you want to go in that direction.

Comment: A well known _trick_ to generate series in Redshift is to select from a different table eg. `SELECT row_number() over () + 2000 as year from arbitrary_table limit 25` will give you a series of `2001 - 2026`. It is a little primitive but works like charm.